# Identity for a sum of product of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

For some fixed positive integers $r_1,\ldots,r_n$, I would like to find a sum:

$$
\sum_{i_1+\cdots+i_n=k}\binom{r_1+i_1}{r_1}\cdots\binom{r_n+i_n}{r_n}=\sum_{i_1+\cdots+i_n=k}\binom{r_1+i_1}{i_1}\cdots\binom{r_n+i_n}{i_n},
$$

where $k=0,\ldots,r_1+\cdots+r_n$ ($i_j$ ranges from $0$ to $r_j$, for $j=1,\ldots,n$).

If reformulate the problem. Multiply $n$ finite sums:

$$
\sum_{i_1=0}^{r_1}\binom{r_1+i_1}{r_1}\cdots\sum_{i_n=0}^{r_n}\binom{r_n+i_n}{r_n}
$$

collect and sum parts such that $i_1+\cdots+i_n=k$. What is the result of every such sum.

I have found similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/839423/256234), but I can not connect it to this problem. Also found a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.10604) which uses probabilistic method to establish several generalisations of Vandermonde identity (which to my dilettante view is somewhat similar to my problem).

Here is a small example just to be clear what I want to achieve. Let $n=3$ and $r_1=1$, $r_2=2$, $r_3=3$. Now take $k=3$, it takes six combinations of $(i_1,i_2,i_3)$: $(1,1,1)$, $(1,2,0)$, $(1,0,2)$, $(0,1,2)$, $(0,2,1)$, $(0,0,3)$ so that $i_1+i_2+i_3=k$ (note that $i_1, i_2, i_3$ can take values at most $1$, $2$ and $3$ respectively). So the sum is:

\begin{align*}
&&{2\choose1}{3\choose2}{4\choose3}+{2\choose1}{4\choose2}{3\choose3}+{2\choose1}{2\choose2}{5\choose3}+\\
&&{1\choose1}{3\choose2}{5\choose3}+{1\choose1}{4\choose2}{4\choose3}+{1\choose1}{2\choose2}{6\choose3}=\\
&&24+12+20+30+24+20=130.
\end{align*}

Comment: you put "$i_j$ ranges from $0$ to $r_j$" : is that an actual requirement ?

Comment: $k=0$ when all $i_j=0$ and $k=r_1+\cdots+r_n$ when $i_1=r_1,\ldots,i_n=r_n$. For some fixed value of $k$, take all possible combinations of $i_1,\ldots,i_n$ so that they sum up to $k$.

Comment: In your example you forgot the following combinations: $(2,0,1),(2,1,0),(3,0,0),(0,3,0)$. Taking them into account the result will be $165$.

Comment: @user Please note, that $i_1,\ldots,i_n$ can take values at most $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ respectively.

Comment: Sorry. I have overlooked this additional requirement.

Comment: understood, but then .. there is not much to do, in the general case

Comment: @G Cab I thought maybe there is some kind of Vandermonde identity which gives exact expression (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.10604) for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I properly understood your question, you are looking for
$$
S({\bf r}_{\,n} ,m)
 = \sum\limits_{\left\{ {\matrix{   {0\, \le \,k_{\,j} \, \le \,r_{\,j} }  \cr 
   {\,k_{\,1}  + k_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + k_{\,n} \, = \,m}  \cr  } } \right.}
 {\left( \matrix{  r_{\,1}  + k_{\,1}  \cr   k_{\,1}  \cr}  \right)
 \left( \matrix{  r_{\,2}  + k_{\,2}  \cr   k_{\,2}  \cr}  \right) \cdots
 \left( \matrix{  r_{\,n}  + k_{\,n}  \cr   k_{\,n}  \cr}  \right)} 
$$
where we can consider ${\bf r}_{\,n}$ as a vector in $n$ dimensions.

If it was not for the limitation $0\, \le \,k_{\,j} \, \le \,r_{\,j} $ the above would be a convolution of the $n$ binomials, giving
an ogf  which is the product of $1/(1-x)^{r_{\,j}+1 }$ as per Renè answer.

With the excursion of $k_{\,j} $ limited to $[0, \,r_{\,j}]$ we have instead a truncated version of the above which we can express as follows.
$$
\eqalign{
  & F(x,r_{\,j} ) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,r_{\,j} }
 {\left( \matrix{  r_{\,j}  + k \cr   k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }
  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,r_{\,j} }
 {\left( \matrix{  r_{\,j}  + k \cr   r_{\,j}  \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,}
 {\left( \matrix{  r_{\,j}  + k \cr   r_{\,j}  \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  - x^{\,r_{\,j}  + 1} \sum\limits_{\,0\, \le \,k\,}
 {\left( \matrix{  2r_{\,j}  + 1 + k \cr   r_{\,j}  \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  \cr} 
$$

Indicating with $t_{\,k}$ the coefficient in the second sum
$$
t_{\,k}  = \left( \matrix{  2r_{\,j}  + 1 + k \cr   r_{\,j}  \cr}  \right)
 = {{\left( {2r_{\,j}  + 1 + k} \right)^{\,\underline {\,r_{\,j} \;} } } \over {r_{\,j} !}}
 = {{\left( {r_{\,j}  + 2 + k} \right)^{\,\overline {\,r_{\,j} \,} } } \over {1^{\,\overline {\,r_{\,j} \,} } }}
$$
we have
$$
\eqalign{
  & t_{\,0}  = \left( \matrix{  2r_{\,j}  + 1 \cr   r_{\,j}  \cr}  \right)  \cr 
  & {{t_{\,k + 1} } \over {t_{\,k} }}
 = {{\left( {r_{\,j}  + 3 + k} \right)^{\,\overline {\,r_{\,j} \,} } }
 \over {\left( {r_{\,j}  + 2 + k} \right)^{\,\overline {\,r_{\,j} \,} } }}
 = {{\left( {2r_{\,j}  + 2 + k} \right)} \over {\left( {r_{\,j}  + 2 + k} \right)}} \cr} 
$$
so one way to express a single term would be through the hypergeometric function
$$
\eqalign{
  & F(x,r_{\,j} ) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,r_{\,j} }
 {\left( \matrix{  r_{\,j}  + k \cr   k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }
  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,r_{\,j} }
 {\left( \matrix{  r_{\,j}  + k \cr  r_{\,j}  \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\,}
 {\left( \matrix{  r_{\,j}  + k \cr   k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  - x^{\,r_{\,j}  + 1} \sum\limits_{\,0\, \le \,k\,}
 {\left( \matrix{  2r_{\,j}  + 1 + k \cr  r_{\,j}  \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,r_{\,j}  + 1} }} - x^{\,r_{\,j}  + 1}
 \left( \matrix{  2r_{\,j}  + 1 \cr   r_{\,j}  \cr}  \right)
{}_2F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{   {2r_{\,j}  + 2,\;1}  \cr   {r_{\,j}  + 2}  \cr } \;} \right|\;x} \right) \cr} 
$$

But now, multiplying the terms
$$
G(x,{\bf r}_{\,n} ) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m} {S({\bf r}_{\,n} ,m)x^{\,m} }  = \prod\limits_{j = 1}^n {F(x,r_{\,j} )} 
$$
leads to a complicated expression.

Conclusion: lacking a "compact" form to express the truncated binomial, tere is not much to do to
render similarly "compact" your sum.

Comment: thanks indeed for the bounty, and thanks twice since I had to give, alas, a .. negative answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is what can be obtained with generating function technique:

${r+i \choose r}=[x^i]\frac{1}{(1-x)^{r+1}}$, where $[x^i]f(x)$ is the coefficient of $x^i$ in the power series expansion of $f(x)$. Then
$$
\sum_{i_1+\cdots+i_n=k}\binom{r_1+i_1}{r_1}\cdots\binom{r_n+i_n}{r_n}=[x^k]\frac{1}{(1-x)^{r_1+\cdots+r_n+n}}={r_1+\cdots+r_n+n-1+k \choose k}
$$

Comment: That does not hold when I take an example. For $r_1=1$, $r_2=2$, $r_3=3$ and $k=3$ it takes six combinations of $(i_1,i_2,i_3)$: $(1,1,1)$, $(1,2,0)$, $(1,0,2)$, $(0,1,2)$, $(0,2,1)$, $(0,0,3)$. And the sum is $24+12+20+30+24+20=130$.

Comment: @user Please note, that $i_1,\ldots,i_n$ can take values at most $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ respectively. This example shows that the result is not Binomial coefficient.

Comment: Ok then my answer is wrong, and it seems to me that the question is much more difficult given these restrictions on the $i_j$. May be investigating the case $n=2$ would give insights or new ideas.